# How to deal with possible fake votes?

Tags: discussion, moderation, site-policies

I saw a question just being added to the site when refreshing the newest actions at the landing page of SP.SE. Once I opened the question, it immediately had **3** votes although the question had been asked 2 minutes ago.

[image]

This doesn't go against laws of physics, but - fellow SharePoint.stackexchangers - we all know this is really, *really* abnormal. In fact to me this is so unusual, that I'm ready to judge the votes as fake votes.

What should we do in situations like this? Fake votes, if being used, are obviously unfair way to e.g. promote one's question or to obtain some reputation which in the end could be even beneficial for an individual in the enterprise world.

Comment: Thank you so much @moe for reporting such behavior, we will check this in details on our side and promise you we will take a strong action for any account violate the SE rules!!

Comment: Even I have noticed it a couple of times for some questions. This is quite abnormal behaviour . @MohamedEl-QassasMVP - should we flag it ? If yes, under what category ?

Comment: Yes, you should flag it at this category **in need of moderator intervention**
*A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!*

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP I think that answers the original question too. You may add it below if there isn't more to be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you suspect voting fraud, flag the offending post for moderator intervention and describe your suspicion in detail. If the moderators determine further investigation is warranted, they will forward the case on to Stack Exchange staff, who have the ability to examine more personal details of who voted and what IP addresses the votes came from, etc., and reverse any fraud and mete out appropriate punishments.